# reading a VHDL output through PLB bus by using Microblaze c code

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm currently using Xilinx ise10.1.I have simulated a Vhdl program for an upcounter.But i dont know how to interface it with PLB bus, so that the microblaze c code can read it via the same bus.Please help me as i'm a fresher in using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

The version 10.1 of ISE is quite old.  So, forgive me if I don't remember everything correct.

If you start the `xps` tool of the `EDK` part of Xilinx, you should find somewhere in the menus a wizard to create a new Microblaze peripheral. This will create a template with a PLB bus to connect to the Microblaze.  You're HDL code can be inserted in the template.

For ISE 14.4:

1. start xps
2. create a new project ('File' -> 'New Blank Project')
3. 'Hardware' -> 'Create of Import Peripheral'
4. 'Create templates for a new peripheral'
5. ....

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to read it occasionally, and everything is running off the same clock, you could just instantiate a GPIO peripheral and connect your counter outputs to the GPIO input lines.

Comment: thank you for your comments.But where should i use the microblaze c code to read the data from PLB(output of VHDL).

Comment: You read the GPIO port - there's a driver and API provided by Xilinx.  Which means you don't have to put a PLB into your VHDL.

Comment: I have done a Vhdl program in EDK and respective microblaze c code is also written.I have followed "http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2008/10/integrating-vhdl-design-into-peripheral.html" link.But i'm using Spartan3adsp starter kit instead of ML505 or XUPV5 board they mentioned.But failed to download bitstream into board.